# Time difference on "ON" clause sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I have this table, date is a TEXT field and the only field.

```
date
2020-01-01
2010-03-01
2010-06-01
2011-01-01
2012-01-01
2013-01-01
2014-01-01
2015-01-01
```

I want the table to join itself on the date that is 1 year smaller than the target record, I tried this. However it doesn't seemed to work when I only add number after doing a `strftime`.

```sql
SELECT d0.*, d1.* from the_table d0 left join the_table d1 on strftime(d0."date",'%Y') = strftime(d1."date",'%Y') + 1;
```

What I want is the following result

```
date           date
2020-01-01     None
2010-03-01     2011-01-01
2010-06-01     2011-01-01
2011-01-01     2012-01-01
...
```

But this is what it returned instead.

[image]

I have several questions regarding this issue?

1. Besides the example that joins table on a specific difference in year. How do I do this for months, days etc?
2. Does the strftime uses the index if there's an index created on that field? The `date` field is the primary key field in the example. How do I know if I'm using indices? If not how do I make it use the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the function [`strftime()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) requires the format to be the first argument and the date to be the second.
Also, `strftime()` returns a string, so you must convert it to a number (implicitly by adding 0) if you want to compare it to a number:

```
SELECT d0.*, d1.* 
FROM the_table d0 LEFT JOIN the_table d1 
ON strftime('%Y', d0."date") + 1 = strftime('%Y', d1."date") + 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2c233e871e6cab77328af9d67c46b382).
Results:

| date | date |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | null |
| 2010-03-01 | 2011-01-01 |
| 2010-06-01 | 2011-01-01 |
| 2011-01-01 | 2012-01-01 |
| 2012-01-01 | 2013-01-01 |
| 2013-01-01 | 2014-01-01 |
| 2014-01-01 | 2015-01-01 |
| 2015-01-01 | null |

You can apply the same code by changing the format to `'%m'` or `'%d'` to compare month or day respectively, if the year is not relevant.

But, if you want to join on the next day of each date you can do it with the function `date()`:

```
SELECT d0.*, d1.* 
FROM the_table d0 LEFT JOIN the_table d1 
ON date(d0."date", '+1 day') = d1."date";
```

Also, `strftime()` and `date()` are functions and normally SQLite would not use any index with these functions.
SQLite supports [indexes on expressions](https://sqlite.org/expridx.html) (also: [SQLite Expression-based Index](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index-expression/)), but I don't think that this would help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer or correction to your current approach, but you could use the `DATE()` function here with an offset of 1 year:

```sql
SELECT d0.*, d1.*
FROM the_table d0
LEFT JOIN the_table d1
    ON d0."date" = DATE(d1."date", '+1 year');
```